# How can I count number of appearance of a value and make it into a new column when querying?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table like this

ProductID | SalesOrderNumber

1         | SO0001

2         | SO0002

3         | SO0001

4         | SO0001

5         | SO0002

I want to query the table into this

ProductID | SalesOrderNumber | SalesOrderLineNumber

1         | SO0001           |  1

2         | SO0002           |  1

3         | SO0001           |  2

4         | SO0001           |  3

5         | SO0002           |  2

Basically, the SalesOrderLineNumber will count the number of time SalesOrderNumber appear. Everytime a same value of SalesOrderNumber show up, SalesOrderLineNumber increase.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, questions asking us to write code for your requirements are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they are not about solving a specific problem with code, but rather are asking the community to do your work for you. Instead, make an attempt at writing code and if you encounter a problem, narrow the question to that specific problem and show what has been done so far to try solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       SalesOrderNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrderNumber ORDER BY ProductId) as SalesOrderLineNumber
FROM yourTable;
```

The difference between this and the other answer is the use of `ProductId` in the `ORDER BY` clause.  You seem to want the line numbers ordered by product id, so this seems to capture the intention.

More importantly:  If the order has no duplicate products, then this always produces the same results -- that is, the results are *stable*.  If you repeat the partitioning key, then you *could* get different results each time you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function, ROW_NUMBER(), for this:

```
SELECT
ProductID,
SalesOrderNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrderNumber ORDER BY SalesOrderNumber) as SalesOrderLineNumber
FROM yourTable
```

The ROW_NUMBER() will count the number of times SalesOrderNumber occurs, as we partition by that.